# how to get input parameters on template tag on controllers

Tags: ember.js

I have following on my ember template

```
{{input id="{{order.id}}"   class="form-control" insert-newline="submitOrder"  value=tracking}}
```

And my controller is below

```
 export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
      submitOrder: function(value, event) {}
 });
```

How can I access id inside submitOrder actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
If Ember handle event handling then you will not get `event` object so in your case you will not get event object if you use `input` helper.
So if you can change `input` helper to normal input html element,

```
<input id={{order.id}} type="text" value={{tracking}} onchange={{action "submitOrder"}} class="form-control"/>
```

Now you will get `event` object first parameter, then you can access all the properties. To get id `event.target.id` and to get value `event.target.value`. ..but in your case, you are assigning `id="{{order.id}}"` so you can simply say `this.get('order.id')`

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
      submitOrder: function(event) {
       console.log('id ',event.target.id);
       console.log('value ',event.target.value);
      }
 });
```

Comment: @ave Well, if a question solves your problem consider to accept the answer so its listed as accepted. Also consider to up vote instead of thank you comments. They help much more if another user finds this page

Comment: sorry forgot it, unfortunately I'm not able to upvote coz I'm less then 15% reputation :(